# How to set the desired color for the background of the safari app extension

Tags: swift, safari, safari-extension, sfsafariviewcontroller

don't scold me for dumb questions, but I need your help, how much I googled - I could not find anything. I don't understand how to change the background of the main SafariExtensionViewController to the rgb I want?

Comment: I started looking into safari app extension development, there is a SafariExtensionViewController where there is a Custom View and it has a NSView class, I need to somehow change the background of this thing!

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is elementary, just make sure you [turn](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483695-wantslayer) `wantsLayer` on.
For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.wantsLayer = true
    view.layer?.backgroundColor = .black
}
```

If you are planning to change the color in a NSView inside `updateLayer()` you'll need to turn `wantsUpdateLayer` on as well.

```
class MyView: NSView {
    override var wantsUpdateLayer: Bool { true }
    override func updateLayer() {
        layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(named: "CustomControlColor")?.cgColor
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could go without layers like this:

```
class MyView: NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        NSColor(named: "CustomControlColor")?.setFill()
        dirtyRect.fill()
    }
}
```